# How to improve performance of my linq query?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I have the following code using Linq.

```
 return (from item in this
          where item.IsMatch(orgid, postcode, shipmentMethod, providerCode)
          orderby item.OrderID
          select item.DTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

For 2 Million records, it needs more than 10 min to return a value.
Could someone help me how do I convert this query to one using `ParallelEnumerable`?

Any other suggestions how to optimize perfrormance are welcome..

*** The above sample refers to my custom class that inherits from `IEnumerable`. The `IsMatch()` method has some conditions inside:

```
public bool IsMatch(long orgid, string postcode, string shipmentMethod, string providerCode)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(providerCode)) providerCode = null;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(shipmentMethod) || shipmentMethod == "0") shipmentMethod = null;
    return (OrgID == 0 || orgid == OrgID) &&
            PostcodeFrom.Length == postcode.Length &&
            string.CompareOrdinal(PostcodeFrom, postcode) <= 0 &&
            string.CompareOrdinal(PostcodeTo, postcode) >= 0 &&
            (ShipmentMethod == null || shipmentMethod == ShipmentMethod) &&                    (ProviderCode == null || providerCode == ProviderCode);
}
```

Comment: I don't think using AsParallel() will help here. How many of the 2 million records pass the `IsMatch()` filter?

Comment: Matthew, i have updated the question

Comment: This is very inefficient if most of the records pass the `IsMatch()` filter. You don't actually need to sort your query results since you only take an object with the lowest `OrderID`. Consider using `Min()` instead.

Comment: Is there a reason the orders are not already sorted by `OrderID` ?

Comment: Have you tried folding your IsMatch() function into the query itself?  The overhead for function calls could be hitting you pretty hard at 2 million.  You'll likely want to organize it such that that the the most likely differences will be evaluated first and keep the string comparisons towards the end.

Comment: Or operations will surely slow down the process.

Comment: Did you run a profiler? The first step when you have a performance problem is to profile the application and see what's happening, then optimize from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return this.AsParallel()
    .Where(p=> p.IsMatch(orgid, postcode, shipmentMethod, providerCode))
    .Min(p=> p.OrderID)
    .Select(p=> p.DTime);
```

As **dymanoid** mentioned, `OrderBy` is needless.

TPL should be able to utilize parallelism in `Where()` and `Min()`